# Spacemacs: Code evaluation and security issue

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I want to turn of the security confirmation for the R language, as described here:
http://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html

So I tried putting the following code in the `dotspacemacs/user-config ()` section of my `.spacemacs`:

```
(defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
            (not (string= lang "R")))  
          (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```

This doesn't have any effect.

If I try to `customize-varibale` as elaborated on the link above, `org-confirm-babel-evaluate`, I always get an error saying that the function is invalid. I have tried combinations with and without the the `setq` command and with and without the brackets around the function.

I can turn off the `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` variable for all code blocks, and it works too, but that's not the ideal case as now any code block of any language would be executed.

Also, how would I add an additional language (say python) to the function above.

Any ideas?

I am new to emacs and am using the following version of spacemacs. 
Using: 0.200.7@25.1.1 (spacemacs)